# Using buttons on web pages. Will Google index their links?

Tags: seo, web-crawler

I want to use the look of standard buttons on my page, but I want web crawlers to follow them as if they were links.

Will Google and other web-crawlers index a web page that has links that look like this?

```
<form method="get" action="/mylink.html"><input style="font-size:10pt" id="my-link" type="submit" value="Learn More..." /></form>
```

If not, is there another way to use standard buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googlebot [does follow forms](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html), but I wouldn't count on it.

Also using buttons for links is generally not a good idea, as pointed out by Dave.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use an <a> tag and then style it to look like a button.  This requires a bit more work though.

In my opinion, when you present navigation options through buttons you run the risk of confusing users.  Users associate clicking a button with performing a task with side-effects.  Users also expect links to take them directly to content without modifying anything.  [Here's an article](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/command-links.html) that supports my argument.

Edit:

Here's a better example of styling a link:

```
<style>
.NavLink {      
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#333333;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
}
</style>
<a class="NavLink">Nav Text</a>
```

Comment: See the "Ask Question" butotn in top right of stack overflow. It's a link. It's a button. I want the same navigation, but I don't want a styled button... Is that confusing?

Comment: But I did point out how you can do that.  You style an <a> tag with display:block;background:#333333;font-size:14px;padding:3px; or something similar.  And that isn't a standard button.